# Reading properties file from a class which is in another jar

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I have a project with multiple maven subprojects. Using Spring, JPA, JUnit.

```
+common
   + WebserviceBindingProvider.java  
+views
   +......
   +src/main/test/TestClass.java
   +src/main/test/resources/mocking.properties

The "common" project has a class that reads the properties file "mocking.properties" that is in the "views" project test folders - src/main/test/resources/
The common.jar is added as dependency to the views project.

The code is something like below.

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/mock_endpoints.properties"); 
props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

When i run the test case i am getting the "props" as null.

Can anyone let me know what i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TestClass.java` should be in `src/test/java/` and your `mocking.properties` should be in `src/test/resources/`.